# How do i get a value of of my python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a small loop that tells me with my own input whether my topping is available or not, but it's not working correctly. I can only get the message that states: "your choice of topping is not an option" but if I give the word "Topping" as a input it works. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
pizzas = {
    'topping' : ['cheese' ,'mozzarella','pepperoni','bacon','basil','garlic','oregano','parmigiano','onion','sausage','tomato','mushroom' ],
}
prompt = "Please pick your topping: "


while True:
  search_key = input(prompt)
  if search_key == 'quit':
     break

  elif search_key in pizzas.values():
     print("Your topping is availbe")

  else:
     print("your choice of topping is not an option")
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great question! You have included all your code, described the problem you are seeing and even provided an extra clue (the word "topping") even when you don't what that means! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

```
if search_key in pizzas['topping']
```

...will return True if the topping (search_key) exists in the list

Answer (score 1):

You are not searching the `topping` list:

```py
pizzas = {
    'topping' : ['cheese' ,'mozzarella','pepperoni','bacon','basil','garlic','oregano','parmigiano','onion','sausage','tomato','mushroom' ],
}
prompt = "Please pick your topping: "


while True:
  search_key = input(prompt)
  if search_key == 'quit':
     break

  elif search_key in pizzas['topping']:
     print("Your topping is available")

  else:
     print("your choice of topping is not an option")
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one key "topping" in dictionary having list of values for toppings then change in code for below one line will be helpful.

```
elif search_key.lower() in pizzas.get("topping"):
```

If pizzas.values() is used then it return object of dict_values. To use in operator here i am fetching only value for topping key which returns list of values as object and so i can use in operator with it and it provides desired result.

Also note that user input is converted to lower case while checking within list to make user input case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly cleaner version would look like this. It means passing input and list from the dictionary to the function that checks if option is in the list.

Your issue was that you were iterating through dictionary keys instead of dictionary values of that key.

```
pizzas = {
    'topping': ['cheese', 'mozzarella', 'pepperoni', 'bacon', 'basil', 'garlic', 'oregano','parmigiano', 'onion', 'sausage', 'tomato', 'mushroom']
}

topping_input_value = input("Please pick your topping: ")
topping_options = pizzas['topping']


def is_option_available(input, key, options):
    for option in options:
        if input.lower() == option.lower():
            print(f"Your {key} is available :)")
            return
    print(f"Your choice of {key} is not available :(")


# Call out the function, which can be used for all choices made.
is_option_available(topping_input_value, "topping", topping_options)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the dict_values to a list with `sum(list(pizzas.values()), [])`

```
pizzas = {
    'topping' : ['cheese' ,'mozzarella','pepperoni','bacon','basil','garlic','oregano','parmigiano','onion','sausage','tomato','mushroom' ],
}
prompt = "Please pick your topping: "


while True:
  search_key = input(prompt)
  if search_key == 'quit':
     break

  elif search_key in sum(list(pizzas.values()), []):
     print("Your topping is availbe")

  else:
     print("your choice of topping is not an option")
```